# How to list all the keys with the same value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

So this is the problem. Let's say we have a dictionary `d`:

```
d = {24:0, 25:1, 27:1, 31:1, 23:2, 29:2}
```

Now I need to get an output which combines all the keys of the values and lists them. Output will be:

```
d = {0:{24}, 1:{25,27,31}, 2:{23,29}
```

I tried to first flip the keys and values of the dictionary and then count? I can't really get it to work.

Comment: Ah yes, found it. Sorry!

Comment: No worries. One tip: using Google to search for similar questions before posting is a _lot_ better than using the search tool on Stack Overflow.